# CORS on flask - uwsgi - nginx stack

Tags: nginx, flask, cors, uwsgi

I am running a flask app behind nginx/uwsgi. I am facing CORS issues when uploading files btw the upload limit in nginx is set to 30M and the same is uwsgi and I'm only uploading 2M of files, and I allowed all CORS origins. I've tried everything but to no avail, the request succeeds when I run it directly from an interactive python session.
I have an endpoint `/result`

```py
@app.route('/result', methods = ['GET',  'POST'])
@token_required
def result(user : User):
    if request.method == "GET":
        d = request.args 
        # do stuff
        return jsonify({'success': False, 'msg': 'Unable to fullfill request' }), 201 
    else:
         # do stuff
        return jsonify({'success' : False, 'msg': 'Missing Fields'}), 201
```

here are the uwsgi logs

```
[pid: 8615|app: 0|req: 1/1] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 820 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:08 2022] OPTIONS /jwt => generated 0 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/2.0 200) 8 headers in 340 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 8615|app: 0|req: 2/2] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 840 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:08 2022] OPTIONS /notifications => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/2.0 200) 8 headers in 340 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 8614|app: 0|req: 1/3] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 826 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:08 2022] OPTIONS /result => generated 0 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/2.0 200) 8 headers in 346 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 8615|app: 0|req: 3/4] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 820 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:08 2022] OPTIONS /jwt => generated 0 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/2.0 200) 8 headers in 340 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 8615|app: 0|req: 4/5] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 840 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:08 2022] OPTIONS /notifications => generated 0 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/2.0 200) 8 headers in 340 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 8617|app: 0|req: 1/6] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 945 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:08 2022] GET /jwt => generated 22 bytes in 14 msecs (HTTP/2.0 201) 5 headers in 190 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 8615|app: 0|req: 5/7] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 951 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:08 2022] GET /result => generated 274 bytes in 14 msecs (HTTP/2.0 201) 5 headers in 191 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 8613|app: 0|req: 1/8] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 965 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:08 2022] GET /notifications => generated 19973 bytes in 25 msecs (HTTP/2.0 201) 5 headers in 193 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
[pid: 8614|app: 0|req: 2/9] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 945 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:08 2022] GET /jwt => generated 22 bytes in 7 msecs (HTTP/2.0 201) 5 headers in 190 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 8614|app: 0|req: 3/10] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 965 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:08 2022] GET /notifications => generated 19973 bytes in 10 msecs (HTTP/2.0 201) 5 headers in 193 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
[pid: 8614|app: 0|req: 4/11] xxx.xx.xxx.xxx () {52 vars in 827 bytes} [Fri Apr 22 18:33:18 2022] OPTIONS /result => generated 0 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/2.0 200) 8 headers in 346 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Chrome OPTIONS response

```
access-control-allow-headers: authorization
access-control-allow-methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
access-control-allow-origin: https://example.com
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Disposition
allow: OPTIONS, HEAD, POST, GET
content-length: 0
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Fri, 22 Apr 2022 18:33:18 GMT
server: nginx/1.20.0
vary: Origin
```

Chrome Console error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/result' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

the error is quite funny because the OPTIONS response has the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header.

Comment: Does the response to the actual request (in addition to the response to the preflight request) have the required CORS headers?

Comment: I use the `flak_cors` package. I don't think the `post` request has the valid cors headers. @jub0bs also sorry for the late reply

Comment: @jub0bs the response to the post request contains the valid cors headers. I think the request doesn't get passed to `uwsgi` because there is no entry in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

When I was setting up uwsgi I had to change nginx's user group. when I check the nginx error logs at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I noticed that there was a permissions issue.
I solved this by changing the user group of

```
sudo chgrp www-data /var/lib/nginx/tmp/ /var/lib/nginx/ /var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/
```

Still can't explain why plain python requests query from my pc was not causing the same issue.

#### PS

Whenever nginx will face an error and returns a response to the browser you will see the cors thing in the console logs. so always take that with a grain of salt especially if you already set the cors headers from flask side correctly.